# What is the meaning of "This will be shown to all users but John"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the following sentence mean?

> This menu will be shown to all users but John.

Does it mean that the menu will be shown to *all users except* John or *only to* John?

Answer (score 11):

In your case, "but" means "except". So, your sentence means:

> This menu will be shown to all users
>   *except* John.